# MVC Html.DisplayNameFor on a complex model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a model with a complex type i.e. User/Addresses/List of Addresses

```
public class User{
public List<Address> Addresses{get;set;}
}
```

On my View I am displaying this

```
<fieldset><legend>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Addresses)</legend>
<table>       
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.Addresses.Street)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addresses.City)
    </th>
<th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Addresses.State)
    </th>

    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.Addresses) {    
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Street)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.City)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.State)
    </td>
</tr>
} 
    </table></fieldset>
```

The DisplayNameFor Street/City/State do not work.

What is the proper way to get the DisplayNameFor on a sub object?

TIA
J

Comment: Try using a simple `for` loop, instead of `foreach`.

Comment: What happens is you do `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.Addresses.Street.First())`? I normally just manually type the labels.

Comment: I want to use dataannotations for the names. Trying to always keep strings like that out of code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I changed

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.Addresses.Street)
```

to

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Street)
```

Do not use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.Addresses[0].Street)` because if you need to edit the first row, you won't be able this way.

Everything works as expected now.

Comment: When I try to use the [0] it gives me a runtime error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Address>'"

Comment: What if Addresses is empty? When the @model directive is given an IEnumerable<model> it figures it out...

Answer (score 4):

In ASP.NET Core, `Html.DisplayNameForInnerType()` can be used instead:

```
@Html.DisplayNameForInnerType((Address address) => address.Street)
```

This can be used both when your current model represents a collection as well as when you want the display name of the properties of an inner model.

However, it is required that you specify the lambda expression parameter's type explicitly (`Address address`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Linq to avoid the indexing error. I used this is my code -

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.Addresses.first().Street)
```

And the following error went away.

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Address>
```

However it's better to use the Name directly using the following statement

```
@Html.DisplayName("Street")
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be better:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Street)
```

will also work in case the list is empty

Comment: Wouldn't it result in a NRE if the list is empty?

Answer (score 0):

To display name for the adress property, you may define an empty `Adress` model

```
{
  var adress =new Models.Address();
}
```

and use it like this

```
 @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => adress.Street)
```

Answer (score -1):

The way you are using `DisplayNameFor` is wrong. `Addresses` is a list and it doesn't have properties like `Street`, `City`, `State`. So how you expect the name to get displayed.

Isn't that simple directly using the names in the view instead of using helper in this case.

Comment: So whats your solution?