# MVC4: how to use Tuple as model in View and DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My first View started out like this:
`@model IEnumerable<ToDo4.Models.ToDoItem>`
This works:
`<th>

            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Content)

        </th>`

When I change the View to use a Tuple, the DisplayNameFor() won't work.

`@model Tuple<IEnumerable<ToDo4.Models.ToDoItem>, ToDo4.Models.ApplicationUser>`

```
    <th>  
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1.Content)  
    </th>
```

I don't understand why the DisplayNameFor() is able to extract the ToDoItem type from the first @model, but not when the IEnumerable is in the Tuple.
What am I overlooking?  Thanks ....

Comment: Why don't you create a view model containing both `IEnumerable<ToDoItem>` and `ApplicationUser` as properties.

Comment: @HM: Thanks for the reply.  That (wrapping the IEnumerable<> in a parent class) has the same problem with DisplayNameFor() -- DisplayNameFor() can't seem to extract the ToDoItem type from the IEnumerable<>.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [MVC Html.DisplayNameFor on a complex model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168288/mvc-html-displaynamefor-on-a-complex-model)
Created a wrapper class, changed the IEnumerable<> to IList<>, and this seems to work:

<th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1[0].Content)
    </th>

Comment: it will crash if you don't have any list items

Answer (score 0):

Your original idea will work with:

```
@using GHCOMvc.Controllers

@model (<IEnumerable<ToDo4.Models.ToDoItem> list, ToDo4.Models.ApplicationUser> user)

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.list.FirstOrDefault().Content)
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```